# Query to Json: Return Each Column Twice with Different Names

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this php code to get all payments (payment amount, the name of the user, the month of the payment) deposited by all users in all months:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT p.id as id, p.amount as amount, 
                          u.name as user_id, m.name as month_id 
                          FROM payment p, user u, month m 
                          WHERE p.user_id = u.id AND p.month_id = m.id;");   

//Add all records to an array
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}

//Return result
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

And this is the json I get:

```
[{
  "Result": "OK",
  "Records": [
    {
      "0": "1",
      "id": "1",
      "1": "250",
      "amount": "250",
      "2": "user 1",
      "user_id": "user 1",
      "3": "jan 15",
      "month_id": "jan 15"
    },
...]
```

Now, I think these `"0", "1", "2", "3"` names/values are not supposed to be there and I must have done something wrong here. Is this the doing of the `json_encode()`? Or is it the way I'm querying the db?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out my answer. Both ways should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issu here is that you are calling fetch_array().

fetch_array() will return an array of index based values as well as key based values. So if you only want the key(name) based values in the array, use the below code.

Try fetch_assoc().

```
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Or  fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)

```
$rows = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
   $rows[] = $row;
}
```